# call http cloud function from firebase angular-ionic app

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is probably something trivial but I am new to GCP and app development.

I have an angular-ionic app that integrates with firebase (I am able to read and write to firestore)  now I am trying to call a http triggered cloud python function.

In my firebase console under functions I can see that the function is present:

```
Request
https://europe-west6-tmaker-bd14b.cloudfunctions.net/generate_tournament8
```

I call the function in my app (running locally at the moment) as :  `generateTournament8(eventRefPath:string)` and the implementation is in the following file:

```
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CloudFunctionsService {


  constructor(private firestoreFunctions: AngularFireFunctions, private alertController: AlertController) { }



  generateTournament8(eventRefPath:string){
    const callable = this.firestoreFunctions.httpsCallable('generate_tournament8');
    var res = callable({'event_ref_path': eventRefPath });

    res.subscribe(async res => {
      const alert = await this.alertController.create({
        header: `Time: ${res.date}`,
        message: res.msg,
        buttons: ['OK']
      });
      await alert.present();
 });


  }

}
```

when trying to call the function I get the following error in the console:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-tmaker-bd14b.cloudfunctions.net/generate_tournament8' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

I think I am missing something trivial. Like not correct permissions.  Can you help me?

Comment: Are you using CORS on your backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't share the code of your Cloud Function, but it seems that you are mixing up [HTTPS Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?authuser=0) and [callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?authuser=0).

On one hand, based on your question title and function URL, as well as on the fact that there is no option for creating a Callable Cloud Function from the Google Cloud Console (which is used for Python Cloud Functions), **your Cloud Function seems to be an HTTPS Cloud Function**.

On the other hand, in your front-end code (`this.firestoreFunctions.httpsCallable()`), **you actually define a callable Cloud Function**.

---

You should call your HTTPS Cloud Function exactly like a "standard" REST API endpoint, either with [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or any other ionic/angular similar library.

---

Note that while Callable Cloud Functions are usually deployed via the Firebase CLI, it may be possible to create and deploy a Callable Cloud Function from Google Cloud Console but you would need to follow the [specification for the HTTPS request and response](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference?authuser=0).

Comment: My function is written in python and it has an http trigger. I suspect you are right. I'll try

Comment: I think you are right. I can call the endpoint as: 
`lucapuggini@lucas-MBP app % curl https://europe-west6-tmaker-bd14b.cloudfunctions.net/generate_tournament8/post -d '{"event_ref_path": "groups/padel_roma/events/t_2020-12-14"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"
{"success":true}
lucapuggini@lucas-MBP app %`. but how can I make it callable as from an authenticataed  google user?

Answer (score 1):

As you're reporting, your function is available at:

```
Request
https://europe-west6-tmaker-bd14b.cloudfunctions.net/generate_tournament8
```

So, it looks like you chose *europe-west6* as your region for cloud functions.

In order to properly configure `@angular/fire`, you need to set the `REGION` token in your root module:

```js
// src/app/app.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireFunctionsModule, REGION } from '@angular/fire/functions';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireFunctionsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: REGION, useValue: 'europe-west6' },
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

See: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md#functions-region

Comment: sorry I think this does not work. I get the same error.  I think I am using an http triggered endpoint and not a callable function

Comment: If it's a "standard" http function, then try calling that specific endpoint via Angular HttpClient. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient